# Nativescript project not running on ios

Tags: nativescript

I am building my first nativescript project and everyting seems to work just fine on android. Now i am trying to build my project for ios and i cannot run it on REAL device. On ios emulator it runs just fine.

Now i took plain empty new project to test with and same issues are there.

> I am running nativescript sidekick on osx machine.
>
> tns --version: 5.0.1
>
> node -v v10.13.0

**so what i have done is:**

1. open nativescript sidekick and create a new project (angular & typescript) with:

Template: "Blank"

Project name: "mobileApp"

Also ticked "automaticly set App ID" which is default

Then clicked on "create project" button

1. When the project was created i edited the Application identifier: "org.nativescript.mobileApp423142542514523462" (to make it unique).
2. next i went to "devices" section and selected my REAL ios device connected via USB and clicked on "cogs" to "autogenerate certificate" for this device (i am using apple FREE account).
3. after that i clicked on "run on device" (cloud build). The build was success only warning i see on the log is: "ld: Auto-Linking framework not found CoreServices" (with the yellow warning icon on the log). While building i see messages like:

> (CLI)  ** EXPORT SUCCEEDED **
>
> Build step completed.
>
> Download step started.
>
> Download step completed.
>
> (CLI) Installing on device ...

**and then finally i see error:**

> (CLI) Unable to apply changes on device: 08049a7cf2271dbb1eacd935968c273a8dd8600e. Error is: Failed to install /Users/.../mobileApp/.cloud/ios/device/mobileApp.ipa on device with identifier 08049a7cf2271dbb1eacd935968c273a8dd8600e. Error is: Could not install application.

**So has anyone else seen this or know how to resolve?**

---

**Next i changed nothing else but changed to local build and got the following error:**

> (CLI) Unable to apply changes on device: 08049a7cf2271dbb1eacd935968c273a8dd8600e. Error is: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/.../Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/'.

**Looked at that path and "MobileDevice" folder does not exist.
Now if i create the missing folders manually and re-run the local build i got the error:**

> [18-12-08 12:43:30.260] (CLI) Skipping prepare.
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:30.260] (CLI) Building project...
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:31.053] (CLI) Xcode requires a team id to be specified when building for device.
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:31.061] (CLI) You can specify the team id by setting the DEVELOPMENT_TEAM setting in build.xcconfig file located in App_Resources folder of your app, or by using the --teamId option when calling run, debug or livesync commands.
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:31.513] (CLI) Xcode build...
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI) 2018-12-08 12:43:34.777 xcodebuild[64353:104753258] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-14460.26/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/RuntimeSupport/MacroExpansion/XCMacroExpansionExtensions.mm:94
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI) Details:  Assertion failed: [value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] || [value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI) Object:
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI) Method:   -_xc_setValue:forMacroName:conditionSet:errorHandler:
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI) Thread:   {number = 1, name = main}
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI) Hints:
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI) Backtrace:
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)   0   -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)   1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)   2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)   3   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)   4   -[DVTMacroDefinitionTable(XCMacroExpansionExtensions) _xc_setValue:forMacroName:conditionSet:errorHandler:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)   5   -[DVTMacroDefinitionTable(XCMacroExpansionExtensions) _xc_setValue:forMacroName:errorHandler:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)   6   __108-[DVTMacroDefinitionTable(XCMacroExpansionExtensions) xc_setMacroNamesAndValuesFromDictionary:errorHandler:]_block_invoke (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)   7   -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] (in CoreFoundation)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)   8   -[DVTMacroDefinitionTable(XCMacroExpansionExtensions) xc_setMacroNamesAndValuesFromDictionary:errorHandler:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)   9   +[DVTMacroDefinitionTable(XCProjectArchivingExtensions) xc_macroDefinitionTableFromDictionaryRepresentationForProjectArchiving:usingPropertyDefinitionsFromSpecificationDomain:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  10   -[PBXBuildStyle _setBuildSettings:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  11   -[PBXUnarchivingBinding readValueForObject:fromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  12   -[PBXObject _unarchiveValuesForArchiveMask:fromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  13   -[PBXObject readFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  14   -[PBXBuildStyle readFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  15   -[PBXPListUnarchiver _unarchiveObjectWithGlobalIDHexString:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  16   -[PBXPListUnarchiver _decodeMutableObjectArrayFromPListArray:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  17   -[PBXPListUnarchiver decodeMutableObjectArrayForKey:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  18   -[PBXUnarchivingBinding readValueForObject:fromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  19   -[PBXObject _unarchiveValuesForArchiveMask:fromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  20   -[PBXObject readFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  21   -[PBXPListUnarchiver _unarchiveObjectWithGlobalIDHexString:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  22   -[PBXPListUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  23   -[PBXUnarchivingBinding readValueForObject:fromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  24   -[PBXObject _unarchiveValuesForArchiveMask:fromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  25   -[PBXObject readFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  26   -[PBXPListUnarchiver _unarchiveObjectWithGlobalIDHexString:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  27   -[PBXPListUnarchiver _decodeMutableObjectArrayFromPListArray:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  28   -[PBXPListUnarchiver decodeMutableObjectArrayForKey:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  29   -[PBXUnarchivingBinding readValueForObject:fromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  30   -[PBXObject _unarchiveValuesForArchiveMask:fromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  31   -[PBXObject readFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  32   -[PBXProject readFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  33   -[PBXPListUnarchiver _unarchiveObjectWithGlobalIDHexString:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  34   -[PBXPListUnarchiver decodeRootObject] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  35   +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:readOnly:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  36   -[Xcode3Project initWithFilePath:extension:workspace:options:error:] (in DevToolsCore)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  37   __82+[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEFoundation)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  38   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  39   _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete (in libdispatch.dylib)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  40   DVTDispatchBarrierSync (in DVTFoundation)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  41   -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  42   __82+[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  43   __58-[DVTModelObjectGraph performBlockCoalescingModelChanges:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  44   -[DVTModelGraphTransactionScope performTransaction:] (in DVTFoundation)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  45   -[DVTModelObjectGraph performBlockCoalescingModelChanges:] (in DVTFoundation)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  46   +[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  47   +[IDEContainer retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  48   -[IDEWorkspace _configureWrappedWorkspaceWithError:] (in IDEFoundation)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  49   -[IDEWorkspace _setContainerFilePath:upgradeToWorkspace:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  50   +[IDEContainer retainedWrappedWorkspaceForContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  51   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool _resolveInputOptionsWithTimingSection:] (in Xcode3Core)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  52   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  53   main (in xcodebuild)
>
> [18-12-08 12:43:34.779] (CLI)  54   start (in libdyld.dylib)

---

**any help would be appreciated. Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

The application is expecting a file at

> Users/.../Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/

but that file does not exist (which is what ENOENT means). So you either haver to create the expected directory structure or else configure your application such that it looks in the correct directory.

Comment: Hello, and thanx for your response.

Yes i noticed, that the folder nor file does not exist. I created those folders and copied cert (.p12) and provisioning profile to there... but still no luck.

Just wondering what files actually should be there ... i mean did i copy correct files there or not?

Any other ideas anyone?